# Facebook SDK LoginActivity shown for a split second even when credentials not needed

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Im building an android app that uses facebook SDK. I have an activity which perform some operations that require facebook login. I designed the activity so the actual Session.openActiveSession() will happen only upon performing an operation that requires it and only when there is no active session present. And when the activity finishes i close the session. So far so good.

But... I noticed that everytime the session is opened (meaning, the first facebook operation performed on the activity), LoginActivity is displayed. Since i have FB android app installed on the device, no credentials are needed, the login is occuring immediatly and LoginActivity closes. But still, LoginActivity is shown for a split second. Its really annoying and looks like flickering of the screen. I would be really glad to lose this.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, it was simpler than i thought. you just add the following style to LoginActivity in the manifest.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
```

Comment: Herp derp. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of the `Session.openActiveSession()` method called `boolean allowLoginUi` needs to be set to `false`. But be careful using it that way. If there is no cached access token, basically if the user hasn't logged into the app before, you may have to figure out some other kind of login flow.

Comment: Thanks. do you have a suggestion of how to check if there is an already cached access token ?

Comment: I just had a similar issue in my app. Instead of checking to see if the session is null do the conditional `if(Session.openActiveSession(session, false, callback) == null)`. If you aren't logged in and haven't logged into the app before, it'll return false and you can run your login flow (using a `LoginButton`, or run the method `Session.openActiveSession(session, true, callback)`). If it returns true, then it'll open the session and you're good to go.

Comment: are you sure about this ? i did as you suggested, i checked 'if(Session.openActiveSession(session, false, callback) == null)' and it returned true, so i didnt open the active session with 'allowLoginUi' true. but when i check 'Session.getActiveSession()' it is null.

Comment: Right. Checking that conditional doesn't update your `Session` object. You have to run `session = Session.getActiveSession()` after checking.

Comment: what ? i just told you that Session.getActiveSession() returns null after this check.